# Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: /home/hisham/Android/Sdk

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, sdk

Been trying to debug this issue for hours! Tried many solutions online, none seems to be working.

```
Build properties not found for package Android SDK Platform 25


File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> 
Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: /home/hisham/Android/Sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 39.749 secs
Error: /home/hisham/Desktop/Dev-PGDoc/ionic_app/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: /home/hisham/Android/Sdk
```

[image: This is the error image when running 'ionic cordova build android']

[image: I have Sdk platform 25 installed]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Finally got it fixed! Not sure which one of the following fixed it though.

1. Change $ANDROID_HOME inside ~/.bashrc from ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk to ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
2. Deleted version 25's folder inside platform-tools folder in the Sdk and installed version 25 again.
   After doing the two above, restarted the system and I am now able to compile and build ionic app to .apk files.

PS : This might be just only in my personal computer, and you might be facing the same issue due to different issue. Hope this helps.